# Prove $H^{k}_\text{deRham} (M \times S^{n}) \cong H^{k}_\text{deRham} (M) \bigoplus H^{k-n}_\text{deRham} (M)$ using Mayer-Vietoris

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I want to show $H^{k}_\text{deRham} (M \times S^{n}) \cong H^{k}_\text{deRham} (M) \bigoplus H^{k-n}_\text{deRham} (M)$ using Mayer-Vietoris only, that is without using Kunneth or anything similar. Using the obvious decomposition $S^{n} = S^{n} - \{(0,..,1)\} \cup S^{n} - \{(0,...,-1) \}$ and induction on $n$ I couldn't manage to get very far by using the exactness of the corresponding Mayer-Vietoris sequence. I remember that in Hatcher a similar exercise for singular homology was proved by passing through to relative homology, so im assuming there is something extra that im missing. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Solution moved to answers.

Comment: @C.F.G As ive said, im familiar with this solution but it uses relative homology, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't saw it.

Comment: What is the problem with $U:=M\times (S^n\setminus {N}), V:=M\times (S^n\setminus {S})$. And presumably you know that $A\times (B\cup C)=A\times B\cup A\times C$?

Comment: @C.F.G As ive said, i tried that, but the exact sequence alone doesn't really give me enough information. If you have any tips as to what i should notice about the maps themselves it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am right here ($m=\dim M$ and $U\cap V\approx M\times S^{n-1}$ and $U,V\approx M$) : $$0\simeq H^{m+1}(M)\oplus H^{m+1}(M)\to H^{m+1}(M\times S^{n-1})\to H^{m+2}(M\times S^n)\to H^{m+2}(M)\oplus H^{m+2}(M)\simeq 0$$ So $H^{m+k}(M\times S^{n-1})\simeq H^{m+k+1}(M\times S^n)$.

Comment: @C.F.G Hi, if you were curious, I finally managed to write a complete solution (or at least i hope i did, haha).

Comment: If you think that is a complete solution, please post it as an answer instead.

Comment: @ArcticChar Done, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove the claim by induction on $n$. The case $n=0$ is trivial since $S^{0}$ is two points, so $M \times S^{0} \cong M \sqcup M$, so the claim follows from additivity of cohomology under $\sqcup$.

Proceed by induction. Write $S^{n} = S^{n}_{+} \cup S^{n}_{-}$ where $S^{n}_{+}$ is $S^{n}$ with the north pole removed, and $S^{n}_{-}$ is $S^{n}$ with the south pole removed.

Our induction hypothesis is as follows: We will have in our LES a map $H^{k} (M \times S^{n}_{+})  \bigoplus H^{k} (M \times S^{n}_{-} ) \to H^{k} (M \times (S^{n}_{+} \cap S^{n}_{-} )$. Identify using homotopy equivalences $M \times S^{n}_{+} \cong M$, $M \times (S^{n}_{+} \cap S^{n}_{-} ) \cong  M \times S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R} \approx M \times S^{n-1}$. Our induction hypothesis is now that the map $H^{k} (M) \bigoplus H^{k} (M) \to H^{k} (M \times S^{n-1} ) = H^{k} (M) \bigoplus H^{k - n + 1} (M)$ (which is given by passing by using a homotopy equivalence)  satisfies $Im = H^{k} (M)$ (As in, the left summand), and $Ker = \Delta = \{ (v,v) | v \in H^{k}(M) \}$.

Define $S^{n}_{+-} = S^{n}_{+} \cap S^{n}_{-}$. Our Mayer-Vietoris sequence is:

\begin{align*}
    ... \to H^{k-1} (M \times S^{n}_{+-} ) \to H^{k} (M\times S^{n}) \to H^{k} (M\times S^{n}_{+} ) \bigoplus H^{k}(M\times S^{n}_{-}) \to H^{k} (M\times S^{n}_{+-}) \to ... 
\end{align*}
Which, by the induction hypothesis, and by the lemma from the beginning, is:
\begin{align*}
    ... \to H^{k-1}(M)\bigoplus H^{k-n}(M) \to H^{k} (M \times S^{n}) \to H^{k}(M)\bigoplus H^{k}(M) \to H^{k}(M)\bigoplus H^{k-n+1}(M) \to ...
\end{align*}
Using exactness of the sequence and the induction hypothesis, we extract the short exact sequence:
\begin{align*}
    0\to H^{k-n}(M) \to H^{k}(M \times S^{n} ) \to \Delta \to 0
\end{align*}
Identifying $H^{k-n} (M)$ with its' image in $H^{k}(M\times S^{n})$, $\Delta$ with $H^{k}(M)$ and using the exactness of the sequence + the linear algebra fact $V \cong V/W \bigoplus W$ for any subspace $W \leq V$ (that may require axiom of choice in the infinite dimensional case), we finally deduce:
\begin{align*}
    H^{k} (M\times S^{n} ) \cong H^{k} (M) \bigoplus H^{k-n} (M)
\end{align*}
All that's left is showing the induction hypothesis still holds. The fact that the short exact sequence leads to an isomorphism with the direct sum follows from the axiom of choice, but we can choose it to "work well" with the earlier needed map $H^{k} (M) \bigoplus H^{k} (M) \to H^{k} (M \times S^{n} )$. Specifically, choose any complementary subspace $W$ of $H^{k}(M\times S^{n} )$ to $Ker(g)$, so that $Ker(g) \bigoplus W = H^{k} (M\times S^{n} )$ and $g$ is consequentially an isomorphism between $W$ and $\Delta$ (finding such $W$ requires Zorn's lemma). Under this choice, $H^{k} (M) \bigoplus H^{k} (M) \to H^{k} (M) \bigoplus H^{k-n} (M)$ is written as $(v,w)\mapsto(v-w,0)$, and so it indeed satisfies both requirements of the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Would $H^{k}(M \times S^{n})\approx H^k(M)\oplus H^k(M)$ be a correct result if I suppose $M \times S^{0} \cong M \sqcup M\implies H^{k}(M \times S^{0})\approx H^k(M)\oplus H^k(M)$? where the problem is exactly in this assumption?

Comment: @C.F.G yes, it would absolutely be correct, nothing's wrong with that assumption

Comment: Tom: read my comment carfully. if my comment were correct then $H^{k} (M) \oplus H^{k} (M)\approx H^{k} (M) \oplus H^{k-n} (M)$ which is not a valid identity.

Comment: @C.F.G Sorry, I thought you wrote $H^{k} \bigoplus H^{k-n}$ in the first comment. Of course it's not true, except for $n=0$. What was your point?

Comment: I asked this because one can use that as base case for induction and deduce $H^{k}(M \times S^{n})\approx H^k(M)\oplus H^k(M)$!

Comment: @C.F.G why? the induction step won't work